# A new year's mathematical mystery

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Sam, Magnus, and Olivia each try to write the number **2020** as the sum of consecutive positive integers.

They each use more than one integer, a different number of integers to the others, and none of the same integers as the others.

How many integers did they write overall? How do you know?

This can be done without a computer programme.

Comment: 4 solutions for 3 people

Comment: ah, my mistake. 'At least one' should read 'more than one'. Fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $402,403,404,405,406=404\times5$
>  $31,\dots,50,51,\dots,70=20\times101$
>  $249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256=4\times505$
>
>  $53$ integers in total.

The solutions correspond to:

> the odd non-trivial divisors of $2020$, namely $5,101$ and $505$.

Comment: rot13(Gurer vf ng yrnfg bar bgure fbyhgvba, fgnegvat sebz sbhe uhaqerq gjb)

Comment: Yep, sorry about the question: 2020 is not a sum of consecutive integers, since it's not a sum. The question should have made that clearer and has been updated.